# Rails 2.3.8: Callback that will happen before save and validation (even when there's no validation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I was using before_validation, to do a few updates to the models before they are being validated and later on - saved.

Apparently, the validation callbacks aren't called when you save without validation.

What callback should I use to make sure this code runs before the save *and* before validation if it exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skipping validation sounds like a workaround. You're better off calling validations conditionally if there are cases when you don't want to validate. That way it's testable as well.

This seems pretty hacky but...

```
def save
  do_something
  super
end
```

Comment: The reason to skip validations, is because some models are deadlocked together with validations (one is invalid before the other is changed, and vice versa).
So, you save both models without validation and only then run the validations (all inside a transaction).

Comment: BTW, does that mean Rails doesn't support a callback that will happen before validation *and* saving?

Comment: As far as I know, no. The Rails API lists the available callbacks in the order that they're available: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Sounds like there's a lot of interdependency going on in which case skipping validations is going to come back to bite you at some point. I'd reconsider that design. That's easier said than done, I know.